# Create a new column based on matching string

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a large dataframe and want to create a new column name Class based on matching data present in perticular column:
Is it possible to solve this using loop or other way

The example dataframe is as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame(
      Function = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
      )
```

and the output look like this

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Function = c("A", "C", "F", "D", "E", "I", "G", "H", "B"),
  Class= c("Class1","Class1","Class1","Class2","Class2","Class2","Class3","Class3","Class3"))
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about the change in row order between `FunctionClass` and `Function` and the many-to-one mapping between `Function` and `Class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an assignment dictionary `A`, using `read.table` for instance, and `merge` the data frames.

```
A <- read.table(text='
A  Class1
B  Class3
C  Class1
D  Class2
E  Class2
F  Class1
G  Class3
H  Class3
I  Class2
')

merge(dat, A)
#   Function  Class
# 1        A Class1
# 2        B Class3
# 3        C Class1
# 4        D Class2
# 5        E Class2
# 6        F Class1
# 7        G Class3
# 8        H Class3
# 9        I Class2
```

The other way round you could write a `list` with classes and the assigned functions,

```
lst <- list(Class1=c("A", "C", "F"), Class2=c("D", "E", "I"), Class3=c("B", "G", "H"))
```

and `Vectorize` a small function so it loops over the functions as well as list elements.

```
class_assign <- Vectorize(\(x, lst) names(lst)[sapply(lst, \(a) any(x %in% a))], vectorize.args='x')

dat$Class <- class_assign(dat$Function, lst)
#   Function  Class
# 1        A Class1
# 2        C Class1
# 3        F Class1
# 4        D Class2
# 5        E Class2
# 6        I Class2
# 7        G Class3
# 8        H Class3
# 9        B Class3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Function = c("A", "C", "F", "D", "E", "I", "G", 
"H", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I have large data frame, and I have to assign , is there any shortcut way like factor or dictionary of class method etc

Comment: @Umar Actually `A` is a dictionary. You can create it in many ways, but somewhere you need to assign each function a class, right? I like the `read.table` approach because it's very readable and easy to change.

Comment: @Umar Actually you can use `merge`, see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way like Class1=A,C,E and so and than create new column, by matching, it will become easy form me, thanks and regards